# Problems with logging handler propagation - messages repeated

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to setup logging for a modules and have the following minimal reproducible example...

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
import logging
start = datetime.now()
LOG_CONFIG = logging.basicConfig(
    filename=Path().cwd().stem + f"-{start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}.log", filemode="w"
)
LOG_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(
    fmt="[I %(levelname)-8s : %(message)s]"
)
LOG_DEBUG_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(
    fmt="[D %(levelname)-8s : %(message)s]"
)
LOG_ERROR_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(
    fmt="[E %(levelname)-8s : %(message)s]"
)
LOG_WARNING_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(
    fmt="[W %(levelname)-8s : %(message)s]"
)
LOGGER_NAME = "test"

def setup_logger(log_name: str = LOGGER_NAME) -> logging.Logger:
    out_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    out_stream_handler.propagate = False
    out_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    out_stream_handler.setFormatter(LOG_FORMATTER)
    debug_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    debug_stream_handler.propagate = False
    debug_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    debug_stream_handler.setFormatter(LOG_DEBUG_FORMATTER)
    err_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    err_stream_handler.propagate = False
    err_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    err_stream_handler.setFormatter(LOG_ERROR_FORMATTER)
    warning_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    warning_stream_handler.propagate = False
    warning_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    warning_stream_handler.setFormatter(LOG_WARNING_FORMATTER)
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.propagate = False
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        logger.handlers = []
    if not logger.handlers:
        logger.addHandler(out_stream_handler)
        logger.addHandler(debug_stream_handler)
        logger.addHandler(err_stream_handler)
        logger.addHandler(warning_stream_handler)

    return logger
```

I read the documentation about `propagate` and have explicitly set it to `False` for each handler and the `logger`.

When I evaluate the following...

```
LOGGER = setup_logger(log_name=LOGGER_NAME)
LEVELS = {"ERROR": logging.ERROR,
          "WARNING": logging.WARNING,
          "INFO": logging.INFO,
          "DEBUG": logging.DEBUG}
for key, value in LEVELS.items():
    print(f"################### setLevel : {key}")
    LOGGER.setLevel(value)
    LOGGER.error("ERROR Message")
    LOGGER.warning("WARNING Message")
    LOGGER.info("INFO Message")
    LOGGER.debug("DEBUG Message")
```

...it results in `LOGGER.error()` being printed four times, `LOGGER.warning()` three, `LOGGER.info()` twice and `LOGGER.debug()` once regardless of the `setLevel`. So the `setLevel` works as I'd expect only outputting the relevant level of messages but I can't figure out why the messages are repeated.

```
################### setLevel(ERROR)
I [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
D [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
E [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
W [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
################### setLevel(WARNING)
I [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
D [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
E [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
W [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
I [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
D [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
W [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
################### setLevel(INFO)
I [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
D [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
E [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
W [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
I [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
D [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
W [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
I [INFO     : INFO Message]
D [INFO     : INFO Message]
################### setLevel(DEBUG)
I [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
D [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
E [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
W [ERROR    : ERROR Message]
I [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
D [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
W [WARNING  : WARNING Message]
I [INFO     : INFO Message]
D [INFO     : INFO Message]
D [DEBUG    : DEBUG Message]
```

EDIT:

Python version is 3.10.9

Comment: Propagation is managed by the logger, not the handler.

Comment: I also have `logger.propagate = False` to prevent propagation and this is one of the reasons why I'm confused. (I thought I'd try them on the handler too and left the code in to show I'd tried that).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is as expected.
You have 4 handlers (all writing to stdout/stderr).

Based on your configuration, an error level *LogRecord* will be emitted by all handlers, warning level *LogRecords* will be emitted by 3 of them... and so on.

Use only one of the handlers (`debug_stream_handler`). You should see the results you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Hrushikesh-v that does indeed result in the expected output. I was hoping to set different formats for different levels of warning though which is why I was using multiple `addHandler()`.